# How to list contents of Amavis quarantine

Tags: mail, amavisd-new

I have amavis and spamassassin configured on my ubuntu wily mail server, it is happily putting spam into quarantine.

Whilst I have been able to find out how to release emails from quarantine, (amavisd-release), I haven't found any documentation for checking the contents of the quarantine to see if you need to release anything. Yes you can check the mail.log or check the quarantine folder directly, but both of these feel wrong. I tried pointing a mail client at the quarantine user's mailbox but get a message that Mail access for users with UID XXX not permitted, so this also feels like this cannot be the correct answer.

How do you go about finding the contents of the quarantine? 
Is there some command I have missed to just list the contents and the mail ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Webinterface written in PHP to browse the amavisd-new quarantine called **MailZu**:

Screenshots and original project page:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mailzu/

Latest fork:
https://github.com/gnanet/mailzu

It also allows users to manage their own quarantine. It requires that amavisd-new uses a database backend to store the quarantine.